# Affected rows after update with OpenQuery

Tags: sql-server, update, linked-server

Is there a way to get the affected row count, when updating through an connection server?

I'm using MSSQL connected to MySQL with ODBC.

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY (MyConnection, 'UPDATE recordid, status FROM table WHERE status=0') SET status=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a modified Linked Server Naming Convention Instead with @@rowcount

```
UPDATE  [linkedServerName]...[databaseName.TableName] 
set status=1 WHERE status=0
select @@rowcount
```

**Note:**

Follow these steps to get Microsoft SQL Server linked server naming convention to work with MySQL:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968343/select-from-mysql-linked-server-using-sql-server-without-openquery

> you can use the statement below
>
> `select * from [linkedServerName]...[databaseName.TableName]`
>
> but before executing the code above ,, you have to do some changes ..
>
> in the SQL Server Management Studio , go to "linked servers" Folder , open Providers Folder , find MSDASQL and gets it's propertythen check "Level Zero Only" press Ok ... then execute above query and Enjoy it !!!